# How to 'show current line' in in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode4

I know you can go to preferences and enable a column that appears on the left part of the editor, showing the line number.

But I am asking is there a way of showing the line number in some kind of status bar or any other part of the Xcode UI without enabling this option (similarly to what Xcode 3 did)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901758/xcode-4-see-the-number-of-the-line-of-code-i-am-on

Comment: The natural place for this to appear in Xcode would be the jump bar. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and reference radar://9245044 to request this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From what I've read so far, I think this option has been removed from XCode 4.
Personally, I leave the line numbers column on all the time and it's not too intrusive.

Comment: It seems this is the case, the option has been removed. Marking this as the accepted answer, thanks!

Comment: I'm looking for the current column number. I suppose the above is my answer :-(

Answer (score 49):

Its not removed..Goto X-Code--> Preferences --> Text Editing --> Check Line Numbers..

[image]

Comment: patel.rohn: That is not what I am looking for. Carefully read my answer and you will notice that I already know about this option.

Answer (score 2):

Dave Keck's [Xcode fixins](https://github.com/davekeck/Xcode-4-Fixins) might provide a good alternative to what you are looking for.  I use XCFixin_CurrentLineHighlighter and it works like charm. 
See the attached screenshot:

[image: Current line highlighted]

The easiest way to try the plugin, and discover new ones, is to use [Alcatraz](http://mneorr.github.io/Alcatraz/).

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for the tip and for mentioning Alcatraz! Great piece of software. Up-voted.

Comment: Xcode fixins are interesting but this question is asking how to show the current line number in a status area, not highlight the current line.  Xcode fixins does not restore the line number in status area feature that Xcode 3 had (and every other coding IDE I've ever used also has).