# How can I find a line number in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I have a function in my *.m file

```
- (void)myFunction {}
```

How can I find the line number this function?

Comment: in the function or in the source file?  The source file is one of the editor options (IIRC)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode -- see the number of the line of code I am on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901758/xcode-see-the-number-of-the-line-of-code-i-am-on)

Comment: Please file bugs at http://bugreport.apple.com and reference radar://9245044 (for showing cursor line & column) or radar://13255659 (to show line numbers in the editor by default).

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You can go to:

```
Xcode > Preferences > Text Editing
```

then tick "Line numbers". Go to your method and you'll see the appropriate line number shown in the left-hand border of the text editor.

Comment: Thank you. I would have liked to have the "Line numbers" feature ON by default.

Answer (score 5):

Go to Xcode Preferences > Text Editing > Show: Line numbers to show the line numbers on the editor.

Answer (score 4):

This can also be done through code when your implementation file grows. I have found this very useful to track and debug through tedious code.
NSLog(@"\nFunction: %s\t\tLine: %d\n\n",**func**, **LINE**);

For example, in some class called MyClass:

```
- (void) someFunction {
    NSLog(@"\nFunction: %s\tLine: %d\n\n",__func__, __LINE__);
}
```

==== Output ===

```
Function: -[myClass someFunction]          Line: 175
```

Answer (score 3):

If you type command L and enter the desired line number, then you can jump to the line number in Xcode 5.

Answer (score 3):

### In Xcode 7

> Xcode > Preferences > Text Editing
>   check the Line numbers

Answer (score 1):

Still applies in Xcode 8

Xcode > Preferences > Text Editing

Answer (score 1):

Shortcut `cmd+L`. Enter line number.

or

`cmd+O`. $CLASS_NAME:$LINE_NUMBER.

And your XCode goes to the line and highlights it!

Answer (score 0):

Keep Xcode top on Mac-Screen than press "command" and "comma key btn" a xcode preferences popbox will open given below:[image] than click on "Text Editing" menu below given window will open [image] here you on top written "show" with "Line numbers" just check it and thats it.

Happy Coding!!!