# Unix command for find number of lines code in iOS project

Tags: ios, unix

I trying to find total number of line code of .h and .m file.I dont know the command for this Please help me.

Comment: Please read this link 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003534/how-to-find-out-how-many-lines-of-code-there-are-in-an-xcode-project 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769918/how-can-i-find-a-line-number-in-xcode

Answer (score 0):

Try with `wc`:

```
wc -l your_file
```

wc stands for `word count` and with `-l` flag it counts the number of lines.

Comment: I somehow received a downvote. Anybody explaining why?

Answer (score 0):

`wc -l your_file` give you the number of lines in a file.

Take a look at [man wc](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?wc)

Answer (score 0):

`find project-dir -name "*.[mh]" | xargs wc -l`

This will find all files that end with the extension m or h and `wc` will count lines in the files. The last line will contain the total.