# XCode 4.6 Syntax color show only blue

Tags: xcode, syntax-highlighting

Now i have reinstalled XCodes 4.6 in my Mac Mountain Lion.

After that all syntax color is show only blue like following pic.

And not show line number.

[image]

How can i do that Please help me?

Comment: Go to Editor --> Syntax Coloring --> Default for this file type

Comment: thanks Jon Marsh. :) i got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the fonts and colors in Xcode's preferences. It even includes a set of "themes" with preset font/color combinations. Check out this link from Apple's developer site:

[Fonts and Colors Preferences Help: Setting Font and Color Preferences](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-fonts_and_colors_preferences_help/Recipe.html)

As for the line numbers, doing a search here on stackoverflow would've helped:

[iphone - Xcode 4 -- see the number of the line of code i am on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901758/xcode-4-see-the-number-of-the-line-of-code-i-am-on)

Answer (score 1):

don't know why that happened, but your setting is found here in Preferences

Preferences -> Text Editing -> Editing -> Show: Line Numbers