# How can I find which line of code is which on Xcode?

Tags: xcode, lines

I am doing code testing with Xcode in an obscure computer programming language (IDL). After compiling, the program outputs there is an error on "Line xxx".

I need to find out exactly which line that is. Unfortunately, Xcode does not show this for IDL, as it does not recognize the language.

Is there a way to manually label all lines in Xcode? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic because this is a user problem with Xcode, and not necessarily a programming problem. It would be better suited on Super User.

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901758/where-do-i-find-the-line-number-in-the-xcode-editor

Comment: @KLibby That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you

Comment: @Zizouz212 I'm deleting the question now.