# Where do I find the column number in the Xcode editor?

Tags: xcode

From time to time I find myself working in Xcode and wanting to know what column the insertion point is at.

The first thing that occurs to me is to look for an equivalent to Emacs' [column-number-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Position-Info.html#Position-Info).  There's a similar feature in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

One work-around is to visit the preferences and use the Page guide.  There's a picture in the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901758/.